# I have disallowed everything for 10 days

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Due to an update error, I put in prod a `robots.txt` file that was intended for a test server. Result, the prod ended up with this `robots.txt` :

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

That was 10 days ago and I now have more than 7000 URLS blocked Error (Submitted URL blocked by robots.txt) or Warning (Indexed through blocked byt robots.txt).
[image]

Yesterday, of course, I corrected the `robots.txt` file.

What can I do to speed up the correction by Google or any other search engine?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: @JohnConde Oh sorry, is there any other forum like Stack Overflow with discussions about SEO?

Comment: @LondonSmith Did you read the link? It tells you where you can ask SEO questions like this

Comment: @JohnConde No it was a bit too long and didn't know I could find the place here. But I did it and it might be there: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the robots.txt test feature. https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool

Once the robots.txt test has passed, click the "Submit" button and a popup window should appear. and then click option #3 "Submit" button again --

Ask Google to update
Submit a request to let Google know your robots.txt file has been updated.

Other then that, I think you'll have to wait for Googlebot to crawl the site again.

Best of luck :).

Comment: Can I set Google Search Console to increase to speed of crawling the Website? For example, 1 page per second.

Comment: You could add the robots.txt directive "Crawl-delay", this will tell Googlebot or other bots "That follow robots.txt rules" to crawl the website at said speed. http://www.robotstxt.org/ read the documentation.